# Merging pairs of rows with one DateTime column into single rows with start and end date columns

Tags: t-sql

EDIT: Much needed clarification regarding the fact that a name can have many pairs of non-overlapping starts and ends. So a merged pairs can be identified as "Run".

I'm guessing this is a duplicate question but I can't seem to find the other one. If someone can point me to it, then this can be closed or deleted or whatever.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Id   Name      Action      ActionDate
---- -------   ------      ----------
1    John      Start       01/15/2013
2    Mary      Start       01/17/2013
3    Nancy     Start       01/17/2013
4    John      End         01/18/2013
5    Mary      End         01/18/2013
6    Nancy     End         01/20/2013
7    John      Start       01/19/2013
8    Mary      Start       01/20/2013
9    Nancy     Start       01/25/2013
10   John      End         01/21/2013
11   Mary      End         01/22/2013
12   Nancy     End         01/30/2013
```

And I need a result set that looks like this using a set based query:

```
Id   Name    Run   StartActionDate    EndActionDate
---- ------- ----  ---------------    -------------
1    John    1     01/15/2013         01/18/2013
2    John    2     01/19/2013         01/21/2013
3    Mary    1     01/17/2013         01/18/2013
4    Mary    2     01/20/2013         01/22/2013
5    Nancy   1     01/17/2013         01/20/2013
6    Nancy   2     01/25/2013         01/30/2013
```

Comment: Will your names have multiple pairs of action/date?

Comment: Is `Name` unique? If not, results will not be reliable.

Comment: Yes, a name will have many pairs of starts and ends. And yes, in the result set, Name will be unique.

Comment: @MarkBostleman If the name will have many pairs, then what id do you want associated with each pair, the id with the start or what?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
select MIN(Id),Name,MIN(case Action when 'Start' then ActionDate End) as StartActionDate,MIN(case Action When 'End' then ActionDate End) as EndActiondate from dbo.Table group by Name
```

Comment: Thanks Anjali, I will update the question, but there is not just one start and end date per name. A name starts and ends many times.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's only 1 record with "Start" and 1 record with "End" for each Name, something like this should work:

```
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Name, T1.ActionDate AS [StartActionDate], T2.ActionDate AS [EndActionDate]
FROM MyTable T1
INNER JOIN MyTable T2 ON T1.Name = T2.Name
WHERE T1.Action = 'Start' AND T2.Action = 'End'
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I will update the question, but there is not just one start and end date per name. A name starts and ends many times.

Comment: So do you want to output the minimum startdate and the maximum enddate, or do you need to output each adjacent pairs of startdates and enddates? In the latter case, whatabout potentially overlapping periods?

Comment: Adjacent pairs, not overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not very clear what `id` you want to return if you have multiple pairs of each `name`, you should be able to use a windowing function like `row_number()` to generate a unique sequence for each name with action and then generate the final result:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, name, action, actiondate,
    row_number() over(partition by name, action
                      order by actiondate) seq
  from yourtable
)
select 
  min(id) id,
  name,
  max(case when action = 'start' then actiondate end) StartActionDate,
  max(case when action = 'end' then actiondate end) EndActionDate
from cte
group by name, seq
order by id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59cee0/3)

Based on your data changes, you should be able to use something similar to:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, name, action, actiondate,
    row_number() over(partition by name, action
                      order by actiondate) seq
  from yourtable
)
select 
  row_number() over(order by name) id,
  name,
  seq run,
  max(case when action = 'start' then actiondate end) StartActionDate,
  max(case when action = 'end' then actiondate end) EndActionDate
from cte
group by name, seq
order by id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7eae3/2). This gives a result:

```
| ID |  NAME | RUN |                STARTACTIONDATE |                  ENDACTIONDATE |
|----|-------|-----|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|
|  1 |  John |   1 | January, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  2 |  John |   2 | January, 19 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 21 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  3 |  Mary |   1 | January, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  4 |  Mary |   2 | January, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  5 | Nancy |   1 | January, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 20 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  6 | Nancy |   2 | January, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 | January, 30 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
```